# Azure Timer Function - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Settings must be of the form "name=value"

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm able to create http trigger functions and execute them no problem, but when I create a timer function, I get the following error:

`The listener for function 'Functions.CheckForWinnersOnTimer' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Settings must be of the form "name=value".`

This is with no alteration of the template code when I create the function.

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
};
```

Why is that? I appreciate any help!

Comment: the problem is related to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package not with the time trigger. We can't help without seeing your settings

Comment: Did you set the `AzureWebJobsStorage ` in the local.settings.json?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. There should be a problem with the settings of local.settings.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is what you faced know.

[image]

Given that there is nothing wrong with your code, I think the problem should be caused by local.settings.json. Note the format of the value of AzureWebJobsStorage.

If you are using a local virtual storage simulator, then you should fill in UseDevelopmentStorage=true. If you choose Storage Account on Azure, then you should go here to copy the values and fill in AzureWebJobsStorage:

[image]

An example of local.settings.json using a local storage emulator:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the insight...really helped me understand what was going on. I'd created a basic function which worked fine, but when I converted it to a timer I go the error you are explaining. I _think_ what is going on is that 'ordinary' functions don't need any storage, so the problem doesn't show itself. But timers need to be stored in a blob (or maybe even a queue?), so you need the storage to work. And that's when you get hit by the error. I found this to be useful when running a development environment:

https://github.com/azure/azurite